# Add textfield to UIAlertView

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, uialertview

Is there an easy way to add an Text field to an UIAlertView an get the text out of it?

Comment: how do you mean 'get the text out of it'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input fields in `UIAlertView` are supported natively by iOS SDK 5 and higher. If you need to support version 4, you'll need a bit of hacking.

I once made some sample code for Montouch. Not very clean but it should give you the idea:

http://wildsau.net/post/2011/01/28/iOS-UIAlertView-with-a-UITextField-a-MonoTouch-implementation.aspx

And, yes, this will be approved by Apple without problems.

Comment: Thanks. Do you no have to do it with IOS 5 and higher?

Comment: No. As the other answers say: in iOS5 you have various options to show input fields.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS5 you can add textfields to UIAlertViews including secure password fields. Here is a tutorial link:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/

Comment: Dude it's a nice tutorial for iOS,but it's not relevant to monotouch what morten is looking for !!!

Comment: Everybody who wants to get into iOS development should at least be able to read and understand ObjC and in addition be capable of translating it into MT. ObjC is the standard for iOS, so I think there's no way around it, even if you go for MT.

Comment: But is the hole point of Monotouch not i dont have to bother about Obejct-C?

Comment: The question was:Is there an easy way to add an Text field to an UIAlertView an get the text out of it? Nothing was said about MonoTouch, only a tag for it. So please forgive me.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5.0 introduced `UIAlertViewStyle`.  There are 4 to choose from, the default one we always had, plus 3 others that include `UITextField`s.

If you want to support iOS versions prior to 5.0 though, you can customize these alertViews yourself (I did this in the app I just released). You can add either/both `UITextField`s and `UILabel`s this way.

I implemented the alertView like this:

```
UIAlertView *changeEmailAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change Email Address" message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

The message (\n\n) has line breaks to make enough room to fit the size of my `UILabel` and `UITextField`.

Then, just add the `UILabel` and `UITextField` as subviews of the `UIAlertView`, the same as you would add a subview anywhere else.

Here is the important part: You need to save the text in the `UITextField` before dismissing the alertView.  I use `-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` to get the entered text and save it in a variable that will be accessible later.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a non-iOS5-only solution, UIAlertViews are just views like anything else. You can subclass them, add additional properties and subviews.

There's nothing stopping you from creating a UIAlertView subclass that has a textfield property, implements the textfield delegate protocol and adds the textfield to its own view hierarchy when you instantiate it.

Getting it to looks nice may be trickier, and doing stuff like moving the other subviews around to make space for the text field may involve some fragile hacks like looping through unnamed subviews within the alert view and grabbing one by index. But this is pretty much the only way to do this on iOS4 and earlier, and plenty of app have taken this approach.